# Placing two columns beside each other in a partial view

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller, partial-views

I am working on a partial in MVC that contains a form in tow columns. However, one of the forms sits below the other. Here is my code.

```
<div class="row">

        <div id="partialColumn1" class= "col-md-12">

            <div class="field padding-left-40">
                <label>First Name:</label>
                <input id="add_Client_firstName-1" name="add_Client_firstName-1" type="text" value="[First Name goes here ]">
            </div>

            <div class="field padding-left-40">
                <label>Last Name:</label>
                <input id="add_Client_lastName-1" name="add_Client_LastName-1" type="text" value="[Last Name goes here ]">
            </div>


        <div id="partialColumn2" class="col-md-12">
            <div class="field padding-left-40">
                <label>Referral Date:</label>
                <input id="add_Client_referralDate-1" name="add_Client_referralDate-1" type="Date" />
            </div>


            </div>
            </div>     
        </div>           
    </div>
```

And the CSS for my two columns.

```
#partialColumn1{   
     float: left;
    display: inline-block;   
}
#partialColumn2{    
    display: inline-block;   
    float: right;
}
```

I am relatively new to this, it's my first project, so any advice is welcome.

Comment: what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I'm sorry, I want the two columns displayed side by side inside my partial view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#partialColunm2` is nested in `#partialColumn1` ;) Try putting `#partialColumn2` outside of `#partialColumn1` :D

At least it worked for me.

DEMO: https://codepen.io/Chesswithsean/pen/gWZGGL

Comment: I looked in Chrome developer tools and was wondering why it was showing all funny. I got sloppy with my divs! Thank you!

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your cols into 6 each one and remove your css, cols already has inline.

```
     <div class='row'>
        <div id="partialColumn1" class= "col-md-6">

            <div class="field padding-left-40">
                <label>First Name:</label>
                <input id="add_Client_firstName-1" name="add_Client_firstName-1" type="text" value="[First Name goes here ]">
            </div>

            <div class="field padding-left-40">
                <label>Last Name:</label>
                <input id="add_Client_lastName-1" name="add_Client_LastName-1" type="text" value="[Last Name goes here ]">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="partialColumn2" class="col-md-6">
            <div class="field padding-left-40">
                <label>Referral Date:</label>
                <input id="add_Client_referralDate-1" name="add_Client_referralDate-1" type="Date" />
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
```